# Moving UIView above image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I want to move a UIView by touch above an image.
I calculated the `CGRect` of the image in the `UIImageView` and in the touchesBegan and the `touchesMoved` functions can move the view.
I've got a `for` loop in these functions (`touch in touches`), in this loop there is the code which moves the view by the touches.
I want to move the view only if it is above the image itself, so I put an `if` just in to the for loop which is the next one:

```
if imageRect.contains(selectedText.frame)
```

The problem is that when I move the view out of the imageRect it stucks.
I cannot move it back.
I want to be able to move the UIView inside the CGRect of the image but not out of it.

Edit:
selectedText is the UIView and in the touchesBegan func I make the variable `toucheLocation` (I have the same code in the touchesMoved func, except the `var toucheLocation = location` part)

```
if selectedText.frame.contains(toucheLocation){
    selectedText.center.x = selectedText.center.x + (location.x - toucheLocation.x)
    selectedText.center.y = selectedText.center.y + (location.y - toucheLocation.y)
    toucheLocation = location
}
```

Edit2:

Here's a bigger part of the code:
(the `var toucheLocation = CGPoint()` part is at the beggining of the class)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: imageView)
        toucheLocation = location
        if imageRect.contains(selectedText.frame){
            if selectedText.frame.contains(toucheLocation){
                selectedText.center.x = selectedText.center.x + (location.x - toucheLocation.x)
                selectedText.center.y = selectedText.center.y + (location.y - toucheLocation.y)
                toucheLocation = location
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: imageView)
        if imageRect.contains(selectedText.frame){
            if selectedText.frame.contains(toucheLocation){
                selectedText.center.x = selectedText.center.x + (location.x - toucheLocation.x)
                selectedText.center.y = selectedText.center.y + (location.y - toucheLocation.y)
                toucheLocation = location
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please show me touchesBegan func. what u done in this

Comment: @Dominik there is an edit button under your question, use it to include all the relevant code

Comment: @Dominik **ALL** the relevant code.. above the edit there is this line `if imageRect.contains(selectedText.frame)`, but in the added code I cannot see it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, right now when the `view` leaves the image, the `if` statement will prevent it's moving. So you will have to change that. I propose the following.

So instead of your current `if` branch (the `if imageRect.contains(selectedText.frame){`), try to use following:

```
if selectedText.frame.contains(toucheLocation) {
    let proposedFrame = selectedText.frame
    proposedFrame.center.x = proposedFrame.center.x + (location.x - toucheLocation.x)
    proposedFrame.center.y = proposedFrame.center.y + (location.y - toucheLocation.y)

    if imageRect.contains(proposedFrame) {
        selectedText.frame = proposedFrame
    }
    toucheLocation = location
}
```

Now it will try to calculate a new frame based on touch all the time. But the

```
if imageRect.contains(proposedFrame) {
    selectedText.frame = proposedFrame
}
```

Will make sure that the frame of view will be update only when it is inside of the image.

Comment: Thank you for your help, with a small adjustment it really worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do somthing like this,

```
var imgView : UIImageView // your imageview on which you wanted to move the UIView

var viewMove : UIView // It is the view which move only over the
```

in touch began Function

```
let minX = imgView.frame.origin.x
let minY = imgView.frame.origin.y
let maxX = imgView.frame.origin.x + imgView.frame.size.width
let maxY = imgView.frame.origin.y + imgView.frame.size.height

let touchPoint : CGPoint // touch point

 if  (touchPoint.x >= minX) &&  // check left margin of View
        (touchPoint.y >= minY) &&  // check top margin of View
        (touchPoint.x + viewMove.frame.size.width <= maxX) &&  // check right margin of View
        (touchPoint.y + viewMove.frame.size.height <= maxY) {  // check bottom margin of View



    /*- If any of above condition is false, it means your view is moving out of imageview boundry  else it is within imageview boundry.-*/

    // give your view new origin to move

}
else{
    // do code to restrict you view to move out of image boundry
}
```

If still something unclear then ask.